# In PyTorch, does the learning rate of the optimizer have to be moved to the GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I use device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu') and use to(device) to move my model and input variables to the GPU.  However, the learning rate, lr, for the Adam optimizer is a float, not a tensor and cannot be moved to the GPU.  Does this mean my optimizer is not running on the GPU?
Thanks.

By the way, if I declare lr as `torch.tensor(1e-3)`, and do `learning_rate = learning_rate.to(device)`, then I get an error:

```
TypeError: _foreach_addcdiv_() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, list, tuple, list), but expected one of:
 * (tuple of Tensors self, tuple of Tensors tensor1, tuple of Tensors tensor2, tuple of Scalars scalars)
```

Comment: In https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/does-item-automatically-move-the-data-to-the-cpu/69629/2, it is stated that "plain python number can only live on the CPU". So, since 'lr' in torch.optim.Adam, https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Adam.html, is a float, I guess it lives on the CPU.